# Python Pygame how to put the rectangle on the center of the screen

Tags: python, pygame

I am really newer to study the python and doing the exercrise 
I want to create an rectange or any other graph such as i use`pygame.Rect(x,y,w,h)`
and set the screen_center by

```
self.screen_rect=setting.screen.get_rect()
self.screent_center=self.screen_rect.center
```

but the rectange's center is not in the screen's center
also i want use `self.b=self.bullet.get_rect()`but it show error
how can i fix it?
here's the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import pygame as p
import sys

class Setting():
    def __init__(self,width,height):
        self.w=width
        self.h=height
        self.flag=p.RESIZABLE
        self.color=(255,255,255)
        self.speed=1
        self.screen=p.display.set_mode((self.w,self.h),self.flag)
        p.display.set_caption("Bullet")
        self.bullet_s=1
        self.bullet_w=100
        self.bullet_h=300
        self.bullet_c=(0,0,0)

class Bullet(p.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,setting):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen_rect=setting.screen.get_rect()
        self.screent_center=self.screen_rect.center

        self.bullet=p.Rect((self.screen_center),(setting.bullet_w,setting.bullet_h))   **<-- not in the center**


    self.b=self.bullet.get_rect() **<-- AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'get_rect'**
        self.color=setting.bullet_c
        self.speed=setting.bullet_s
#        self.centery=float(self.bullet.centery)
    def bullet_move(self):
        self.y -= self.speed
        self.bullet.y=self.y
    def draw_bullet(self,setting):
        self.rect=p.draw.rect(setting.screen,self.color,self.bullet)


def game():
    p.init()
    setting=Setting(1200,800)
    bullet=Bullet(setting)


    while True:
        for event in p.event.get():
             if event.type == p.QUIT:
                 sys.exit()
        setting.screen.fill((255,0,0))
        bullet.draw_bullet(setting)
        p.display.flip()
game()
```

Comment: What is `self.bullet.get_rect()` supposed to do? `self.bullet` is already a `Rect`.

Comment: how can i make the rect center same as the screen center??

Comment: `self.bullet.center = self.screen_rect.center`

Comment: instead of name `self.bullet` you should better use name `self.rect` which better describe what you have in this variables. And you don't have to assign `p.draw.rect()`  to `self.rect` - you already have this value in `self.bullet`

Comment: thanks ！！！ i got i , for the`self.bullet=p.Rect((self.screen_center),(setting.bullet_w,setting.bullet_h)) ` is already rect ,so i can use `self.bullet.center =self.screen_rect.center` to do it

Comment: BTW: in class it is better to use methods without prefix/postfix `bullet_`/`_bullet` - this way you may have the same method `move()` and `draw()` in class `Bullet` and any other class which you will create in future - it helps to keep all items on list or in `Group()` and run `move()` and `draw()` for all items - you don't have to check if you have to run `move_bullet` or `move_alien` or `move_player`.

Comment: BTW: i'm not sure but it should also works `p.Rect(center=self.screen_center, ...)`

Comment: Can i ask one more question, for i want to use the key to control the rectangle so i write as `def bullet_move(self,setting):
        for event in p.event.get():
            if event.type == p.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == p.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key ==p.K_UP:
                    print("space")
                    p.draw.rect(setting.screen,self.color,self.bullet)` the print commad is output correctly but when i press up key there;s no rectangle on the screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202803/discussion-between-m-sea-and-furas).

Comment: better create new question on new page - you will have more space for code and description. Game should have only one loop `for event in p.event.get()`. If you use two loops then first can get all information about pressed buttons and second loop will get nothing. Bullet should get only event as argument and check it with `if/else`

Comment: there can be other problem - system sends event `KEYDOWN` only once - when key change state from not-pressed to pressed but it doesn't send events when you keep pressed thiskey. Similar with `KEYUP` - it sends event when key change state from pressed to not-pressed. SO you can use `KEYDOWN` to set `speed = 1` and `KEYUP` to set `speed = 0` and then you can add speed to `x` in every loop. OR you would have to use [p.key.get_pressed()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to get `True` when you keep pressed this key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code center rectangle on screen using

```
 self.screen_rect = setting.screen.get_rect()

 self.rect.center = self.screen_rect.center
```

It also moves rectangle when you press `UP` or `DOWN`.

It uses `KEYDOWN`, `KEYUP` to change `speed` and it runs `move()` in every loop and this function uses `speed` to change position (without checking keys).

It also compare `rect.top` with `screen.top` and `rect.bottom` with `screen.bottom` to stop rectangle when it touchs border of the screen.

---

BTW: I also add spaces and empty lines in code to make it more readable.

See: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

```
import pygame as p

class Setting():

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.w = width
        self.h = height
        self.flag = p.RESIZABLE
        self.color = (255, 255, 255)
        self.speed = 1

        self.screen = p.display.set_mode((self.w, self.h), self.flag)

        p.display.set_caption("Bullet")

        self.bullet_s = 1
        self.bullet_w = 100
        self.bullet_h = 300
        self.bullet_c = (0, 0, 0)


class Bullet(p.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, setting):
        super().__init__()

        self.setting = setting

        self.screen_rect = setting.screen.get_rect()

        self.rect = p.Rect(0, 0, setting.bullet_w, setting.bullet_h)
        self.rect.center = self.screen_rect.center

        self.color = setting.bullet_c
        self.speed = 0 #setting.bullet_s

    def move(self):
        self.rect.y -= self.speed

        if self.rect.top < 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
        elif self.rect.bottom > self.screen_rect.bottom:
            self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

    def draw(self):
        p.draw.rect(self.setting.screen, self.color, self.rect)

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == p.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == p.K_UP:
                self.speed = self.setting.bullet_s
            elif event.key == p.K_DOWN:
                self.speed = -self.setting.bullet_s

        elif event.type == p.KEYUP:

            if event.key == p.K_UP:
                self.speed = 0
            elif event.key == p.K_DOWN:
                self.speed = 0

def game():
    p.init()
    setting = Setting(1200,800)
    bullet = Bullet(setting)

    running = True
    while running:
        for event in p.event.get():
             if event.type == p.QUIT:
                 running = False
             bullet.handle_event(event)

        bullet.move()

        setting.screen.fill((255, 0, 0))
        bullet.draw()
        p.display.flip()

    p.quit()


game()
```

Answer (score 0):

This will calculate the position from the top-left corner of the sprite

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1080, 720))

def getcenter(sprite):
    screen_size = screen.get_size()
    sprite_size = sprite.image.get_size()
    
    center_x = screen_size[0]/2 + sprite_size[0]/2
    center_y = screen_size[1]/2 + sprite_size[1]/2

    return (center_x, center_y)

getcenter(spritehere)
```